# Как найти пересечение и и число принадлежащее этого пересечения

Tags: java

Подскажите новичку как дальше приступить к решению.

Задается список (до 10 элементов) подмножеств множества вещественных чисел, каждое из которых может иметь вид:

1. (-∞, x1] U [x2, +∞)
2. [x1, x2]

Требуется решать следующие задачи:

1. Для любого заданного числа x возвращать число, принадлежащее пересечению подмножеств, максимально близкое к x (или само число x, если оно принадлежит пересечению подмножеств). Решение должно быть максимально эффективно с точки зрения производительности вычисления, так как будет вызваться очень часто.
2. Возвращать пересечение подмножеств в виде списка отрезков и полуинтервалов.

Вот мой код на данный момент:

```
public class LineSegment {

    public static class Point {
        public final double x;
        public final double y;

        public Point(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
        }
    }

    private final Point firstSegPoint;
    private final Point secondSegPoint;

    public LineSegment(Point firstSegPoint, Point secondSegPoint) {
        this.firstSegPoint = firstSegPoint;
        this.secondSegPoint = secondSegPoint;
    }

}
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, очень нужен алгоритм!

Comment: можно пример: [вводимые данные]-[результат] !?

Comment: dgzargo, здесь нужен алгоритм! Так точно не получится.

Comment: capfer, ты меня не понял! можешь показать как алгоритм должен действовать, что должен делать!?

Comment: dgzargo, Вот задание:https://github.com/Capfer12/zadanie/blob/master/MyAPI/src/test.pdf

Comment: кое-что понял, немного объясню. для первой задача решается "в лоб". вторая: тебе удобно будет если сделать метод склеивающий отрезки с вырезанными точками. склеивая негативы от промежутков задача сводится к более простой: превратить в "негативы" и склеить их)